# creating an 'if' statement based on whether a value exists in a data table

Tags: vb.net, search, if-statement, datatable

I am using VB in a current project and I am having a bit of trouble returning a value from a datatable search so that I can use it as a condition to proceed with the process.

Basically I have defined the datatable and added a column:

```
Public Shared objDataTable As New DataTable("Data Table 1")
objDataTable.Columns.Add("PartID", GetType(String))
```

Then when a value is entered into the GUI by the user it looks for the value in the table using:

```
objDataTable.Select("PartID ='" & _in_id & "'")
```

The next thing I wish to do and the thing I am having trouble with is how I would say:

If part exists in datatable 1 then 
proceed
else
error message
end

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The msdn tells, that [DataTable#Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an array of `DataRow` objects, so you could base the if statement on the length property of the return value (0 means nothing found in the database).